# How to get a converted date object from a string in the expected date format?

Tags: python, date, datetime, object

My code below contains tabulation with *sort_table* method which provides sorting table data by particular column. In this example it should sort by DATE column and it does when column data is date object(NOT STRING):

```
def sort_table(table, col_index, reversed_sorting):
    sorted_list = []
    for row in sorted(table, key=operator.itemgetter(col_index), reverse=reversed_sorting):
        sorted_list.append(row)
    return sorted_list        
  
def retrieve_sorted_by_date_all_the_events(path, sheet_name):
    events_list = retrieve_unsorted_all_the_events(path, sheet_name, 'DATE')    
    print(tabulate(sort_table(events_list, 1, False), headers=[colored('DATE', 'yellow'), 'HOME', 'RIVAL'], tablefmt='orgtbl'))
```

*events_list* contains date objects which are retrieved from EXCEL and converted in the following way:

```
  cell_date = "A" + str(row)
  cell_date_value = w_sheet[cell_date].value
  cell_date_object_value = arrow.get(cell_date_value, "D.M.YY").date()
```

The problem here is that *date()* retrieves date object only in one default format:
**"YYYY.M.D"**

How to keep date object with any other date format(for instance "D.M.YY"), WITHOUT CONVERTING TO STRING?

Comment: [date objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) are a binary representation of a date, they have no format. only a string that represents a date has a format. If you need to sort by day of month (via dd-mm-yyyy format), you'll need to convert to string or sort on a specific attribute of the date, e.g. `.day`.